# Distributed field collapsing in solr

Tags: solr, distributed, fieldcollapsing

I am trying to achieve disrtibuted field collapsing in solr. I tried applying the patch https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1683 but it didnt seem to work. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: The place to post this is the JIRA issue itself. Add all relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

It implements in 4.0, and called it as "group". 
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing

Answer (score 0):

I have taken a look at this patch, myself, and it seems to be for an older implementation of FieldCollapsing, where the query parameters are called "collapse" instead of "group" in Solr 4.0